# Doesn't include signing certificate in xcode8.1

Tags: ios10, xcode8

it is working fine in xcode7.2 on same machine. here I am not using automatic code signing. when i select Provisioning profile tab manually it shows error Provisioning profile doesn't include signing certificate.Also Removed provising profile,certificate from machine and redownload still it's not working and also remove derived data from xcode.but results are same.[image]